# How do i get Payment Token from STPPaymentMethodsViewController using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, stripe-payments

I'm using `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` for Stripe payment. Can anyone help me how can I get the payment token from its delegate method?

```
let paymentMethodViewController = STPPaymentMethodsViewController(configuration: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared(),
                                                                 theme: STPTheme.default(),
                                                                 customerContext: self.customerContext,
                                                                 delegate: self)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentMethodViewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So How can I get payment token using its delegate method so that I can send that token to my server?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can implement its delegate method

Comment: I have already implemented its delegate method but which delegate method can be used to get the payment token? @RahulGUsai

Comment: use https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate.html stpaddcardviewcontroller

Comment: Can you please read my question again? I have used STPPaymentMethodsViewController not 
STPAddCardViewController. @RahulGUsai

Comment: yes i have read your question carefully and thats why i have given you documentation link that using stpaddcardview controller you can get token because its delegate method returns token please refer documentation link which i have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the payment method in the `didSelectPaymentMethod` [delegate function](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate(im)paymentMethodsViewController:didSelectPaymentMethod:). Note that this is just the current method the user has selected, not the final one — their choice is final when your `didFinish` [delegate function](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate(im)paymentMethodsViewControllerDidFinish:) is called. You should save the payment method from `didSelect` in a local variable and only use it once the user is finished with the STPPaymentsMethodViewController.

As a very rough outline :

```
class MyVC: UIViewController{
  var currentPaymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod?

  ....

  extension MyVC: STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate {
        ...

        func paymentMethodsViewController(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didSelect paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod) {
            print("didSelectPaymentMethod")
            currentPaymentMethod = paymentMethod
        }

        func paymentMethodsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController) {
           self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
  }
}
```

Once you have the payment method, and your user has completed your checkout flow and is ready to pay, you can cast the `STPPaymentMethod` to get the stripe ID, which you can then pass to your backend and use as the `source` parameter when [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/#create_charge-source):

```
var paymentStripeId: String?
if let source = paymentMethod as? STPSource {
    paymentStripeId = source.stripeID
}else if let card = paymentMethod as? STPCard {
    paymentStripeId = card.stripeID
}
// pass paymentStripeId to your backend
```

Comment: Thank you @karllekko for your reply. I know this thing. Now can you please tell from selectedPaymentMethod how can I generate the final payment token that I want to send to server?

Comment: @SagarUnagar I've edited the answer. Basically you want to cast the STPPaymentMethod, and then get the stripeId property, which you can use in charge creation.

Comment: Thanks @karllekko for your edits! Can you please tell me how can I generate payment token instead of card token? My backend server needs the payment token.

Comment: @SagarUnagar what do you mean exactly by payment token?

Comment: Payment token look like `tok_1CjW4EL6UpNJN4PNnpNNA8Q3` and Card token look like `card_1Cjn4fLCkY2Mr3fjQKLeuiUA`. I need final payment token which look like `tok_1CjW4EL6UpNJN4PNnpNNA8Q3`.

Comment: You should be able to pass either of those to the Stripe charge endpoint to create a charge.